# How to design div & menu like this

Tags: css, html

[image]I am designing a menu in HTML5.
Can somebody tell me how to achieve what is in the attached image?
Currently I am not able to fill the gap between Menu image(green) & div background color(sky blue)

[image: Example]

Comment: Please push some code for better understanding

Comment: Provide some relevant code/fiddle.

Comment: Friends i am new to html5 & css3 and testing code with reference to this link http://www.joepettersson.com/jquery-powered-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the "BLUE BRIDGE" is separate image, on each page with the particular menu-tab being active re-position the image by setting its margin-left property.

You can use Javascript.

```
getElementByID('blue-bridge').style.marginLeft = "position px";
```

If you are using a master page to build your website, then you can pass a simple variable holding the appropriate position to the Javascript function.

EX: in a php master page:

on content page:

```
<?php
    $ml=5px; //10px //20px .. depending the page.
    include('masterpage.php');
?>
```

on master page:

```
function setMargin()
{
    getElementByID('blue-bridge').style.marginLeft = "<?php echo $ml; ?>px";
}
```

Have a good day.

edit 1: forgot to tell; Use ID in the appropriate tag holding the particular image. :)

Answer (score 0):

z-index the menu higher, and place the blue under the green?